# Cross-Validation probability

Tags: regression, cross-validation

I'm fitting a bulge-disc [sersic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sersic) model to galaxy light profiles and need to find a robust method of finding the errors on the parameters.

I'm looking at cross-validation implemented in this paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3754) (page 9, section 4.2).

It says I need to calculate the likelihood that the point has been left out. How do I compute this? I'm not a statistician and my online research has only confused me! I've never looked at likelihoods before!

Comment: It's not asking for the "likelihood *that* the nth point has been left out" (which would suggest a probability), it's saying "find the likelihood *for* the nth point that has been left out". That is, it is saying *evaluate the likelihood function* for that point.